# What's the best way to test a P2P live streaming app?

Tags: testing, streaming, video-streaming, p2p

I've been working on a P2P live streaming app and I'm having some trouble testing it properly.

At the moment, I'm testing it using:
1) Another laptop + an external server
2) Multiple instances running on different ports

Problem is: this is not exactly ready for production.

Is there something like a simulator OR any of you guys worked on a torrent client, p2p client, live streaming solution and had to test it?

Please let me know,

Thanks,

-hbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what behavior you're trying to test, you might end up needing several different tools.  I happen to have done some research in this area, and when I wanted to simulate various network conditions like limited bandwidth and/or packet loss, I turned to a Linux feature called [Queuing Disciplines](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linux+queuing+disciplines).  Learning how to use them might take you a couple of days, but they're very powerful and completely free.

Comment: Best _looking_ answer so far. I will investigate further and post something here. Thanks again.
http://linux-ip.net/articles/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Put it on a server and send the link to as many of your friends as you can, asking if they could access it so you could test the app. Think of it as kind of a closed beta release.

Answer (score 0):

**Automate The Testing**

Mock the connection to the other client(s), then you can write several different test cases for behaviour of the other client(s). Test if one client goes down, test for slow responses, test for incorrect answers, test for all correct behaviour.